# How to join two tables in SQL Server or C# linq query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables but I don't get what I am looking for help.

My tables are here below. I want to use join in SQL or C# Linq query.

**Table 1**:

```
InvestmentID    UserID  RefNo       Amount  StatusID
----------------------------------------------------
1               1       BPWM2M4G55  1450    4
2               5       BPWM67A7A7  540     2
3               2       BPWM67B7K7  910     2
```

**Table 2**

```
ID  InvestmentID    InvestorID  AssistorID  Amount  RefNo
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   1               1           2           1450    BPWM2M4G55
2   1               5           1           540     BPWM67A7A7
3   3               2           1           910     BPWM67B7K7
```

Output must be like

```
RefNo       Amount  InvestmentID    StatusID
--------------------------------------------
BPWM67A7A7  540     1               2
```

Current code in SQL:

```
Select 
    b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID,StatusID
from 
    Investment a 
join 
    Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.InvestmentID
where  
    b.InvestorID != 1
```

Current output:

```
RefNo       Amount  InvestmentID    StatusID
--------------------------------------------
BPWM67A7A7  540     1               4
BPWM67B7K7  910     3               2
```

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Well so far the output is exactly what you're asking for in the current SQL. Could you update the question with what you're actually looking to accomplish?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki OP already posted the code

Comment: Your query does not have filter `b.InvestorID != 2`. Include this filter too in where clause as `where  b.InvestorID !=1 and b.InvestorID != 2`

Comment: @Viki888 the problem is status it give me 4 but the status is 2.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to suggest changes if the problem statement isn't in the actual question. @Viki888 that would indeed bring the output requested. But if the dataset gets bigger it could potentially no longer bring what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Dlamini.M So you only want results with statusID = 2 ?

Comment: Removed unnecessary taqs since those are not related to the question

Comment: @Dlamini.M meanwhile, there are so many QAs in SO, so many tutorials and examples about joins with linq.. do some research

Comment: @Zephire Yes I only want the result with `statusID=2 and InvestmentID=1`

Comment: Than add both those requirements on the bottom of your existing query ...  `where b.InvestorID != 1 and statusID=2 and InvestmentID=1`

Comment: @Zephire result is null

Comment: @Zephire There is no record with `InvestmentID=1` and `statusID=2`. For `InvestmentID=1`, there is only value `4` exist for `statusID`. The sample data and expected data seems to be unclear.

Comment: correct, based on the data you have shown in the above question, those requirements should return null. So either the data contains faulty data, or your not formulating your requirements correctly. Either one of those is equally bad when jumping into SQL. @Viki888 totally agree

Answer (score 0):

Use the below condition.

```
Select b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID,StatusID
from Investment a join Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.InvestmentID
where  b.InvestmentID =1 and  b.InvestorID !=1
```

Comment: `where  b.InvestmentID ==1` this won't even compile

Comment: @Rahul I noted that error he / she made mistake for putting == instead of = but still giving me wrong result

Comment: @Rahul Edit the answer, wrongly put the == instead of =

Comment: @Dlamini.M try the following
Select b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID,StatusID
from Investment a join Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.ID
where  b.InvestmentID =1 and  b.InvestorID !=1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Select b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID,StatusID
from Investment a join Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.InvestmentID
where  b.InvestorID !=1 and a.StatusID =4
```

Add `a.StatusID =4` or b.RefNo='BPWM67A7A7' in `where` condition.

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL Server`, use this (like Balaji suggested).

```
Select b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID, a.StatusID
from Investment a join Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.InvestmentID
where  a.StatusId = 4 and a.InvestmentID = 1
```

For C#, try this

```
var output =
from t1 in context.table1
join t2 in context.table2 on t1.RefNo = t2.RefNo
where t1.StatusID == 4 and t1.InvestmentID == 1
select new {t1.RefNo, t1.Amount, t1.InvestmentID, t1.StatusID};
```

Comment: Investment_Line no column called StatusId

Comment: @Dlamini.M Fixed.

Comment: yes you did but still it give me the wrong result. status it give me 4 but the status is 2

Comment: @Dlamini.M try join the table 1 investmentID and table 2 ID, that should work. to achieve your result Select b.RefNo, b.Amount, a.InvestmentID,StatusID from Investment a join Investment_Line b on a.InvestmentID = b.ID where b.InvestmentID =1 and b.InvestorID !=1